# Changing variable in topological groups

Tags: integration, topological-groups

Let $G \subset GL_n(F)$ be a locally compact group endowed with its Haar measure. Two typical automorphism of $G$, involutions even, are the transposition and inversion. Is it clear that we have the right to change variables
$$\int_G f(g) dg = \int_G f({}^tg)dg = \int_G f(g^{-1})dg \quad ?$$

Comment: What's transposition here?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Say it is a subgroup of $GL_n$, this is the case I need. But I wonder if something only depends on... the fact that it is an involution?

Comment: The transpose of an element of a subgroup $G$ of $GL_n$ doesn't have to belong to $G$.

Answer (score 0):

The groups $G$ for which you always have$$\int_Gf(g)\,\mathrm dg=\int_Gf\left(g^{-1}\right)\,\mathrm dg,$$and some locally compact groups are not unimodular. One such group is the group $G$ of those matrices of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\0&x^{-1}\end{bmatrix},$$with $x\in(0,\infty)$ and $y\in\Bbb R$.

Note that, in general, if $M\in G$, $M^t\notin G$. So, your other question makes no sense.